# Rsync "permission denied" error using Vagrant's docker provider on Windows

Tags: docker, vagrant, rsync, boot2docker

Just installed vagrant 1.7.4 from official website, besides other software: Virtual Box, cygwin(rsync and openssh). Other boxes like ubuntu/trusty or centos/7 seem to work. Error came up when I tried to use docker as provider.
Here's my vagrant file

```rb
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.103"
  config.ssh.insert_key=true
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    #d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "vagrantfile-boot2docker"
    d.build_dir = "."
  end
  ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"] = ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"].to_s + " cygwin"
end
```

Here's what's going on in console.

> ```
> $ vagrant up
> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
> ==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
>     default: Docker host VM is already ready.
> ==> default: Syncing folders to the host VM...
>     default: The machine you're rsyncing folders to is configured to use
>     default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script rsync to automatically
>     default: enter this password, so you'll likely be prompted for a password
>     default: shortly.
>     default:
>     default: If you don't want to have to do this, please enable automatic
>     default: key insertion using `config.ssh.insert_key`.
>     default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/f/st***/Pre*****/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_1447743654_45276
> There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
> Please inspect the error message below for more info.
>
> Host path: /cygdrive/f/st***/Pre*****/
> Guest path: /var/lib/docker/docker_1447743654_45276
> Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2201 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o
> IdentitiesOnly=true -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --exclude
> .vagrant/ /cygdrive/f/st***/Pre*****/
> docker@127.0.0.1:/var/lib/docker/docker_1447743654_45276
> Error: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2201' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
> rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
> ```

As I understand problem with permissions, but I am not sure what permissions boot2docker's or host's.
I'm also tried without config.ssh.insert_key=true - same result.

**Update:**
Tried to execute big rsync command from log manually. Error was shown

> connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused

but direct connection using **ssh docker@127.0.0.1 -p 2201** was successfull.

So maybe problem is rsync command uses incorrect port.

**Update2** 
Finally,  `rsync -e 'ssh -p 2201' --rsync-path='sudo rsync' -avz /cygdrive/f/st***/Pre****/ docker@127.0.0.1:/var/lib/docker/docker_1447763422_11407` synced everything as it should be without any problem. But question is open why vagrant is not doing it properly.

Comment: Note the error message when you tried to run rsync manually and the port it's using. To test it properly you will need to specify the port number by wrapping the `ssh -p` call into a `-e` flag like:  `rsync -e 'ssh -p 2222' ...`

Comment: It asked me password for 'docker' user, I used 'tcuser' and got 'skipping directory .' line as result output.

Comment: Also I specified -avz flag. Synced only some files other failed due permission denied error. But somehow it worked.

Comment: When running `vagrant up` did it prompt for a password? It mentions it might do so but it's difficult to see if it did from the output. Looks like it's failing to auth though

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't.